# Recyclerview items are getting disturbed on scrolling up and down

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

In `recyclerview` , when i scrolls up or down, the items are getting messed up.That means it recycles the itemviews again. Please someone help me out, I have been trying it so many times. Thanks in advance.

here is the screenshots of the issue
the text view 1(marked red color in the image) is appearing in wrong position when i scroll up and down

image 1: [initial list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKrNK.png)
image 2: [after scrolling list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw0x4.png)

```
private class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PendingFollowupVO> mPendingFollowupVO;


    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<PendingFollowupVO> mpendingfollow) {
        mPendingFollowupVO = mpendingfollow;
        setHasStableIds(true);

    }

    //A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout,
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_pending_follow_up, parent, false);
       ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        //ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),R.layout.layout_pending_follow_up,parent,false);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    // It will specified the postion of the elements
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {




        //ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding=holder.getViewDataBinding;
        //List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(customerIdlist));
        final PendingFollowupVO mpendingfollow = mPendingFollowupVO.get(position);
        holder.linearLayout.setTag(mPendingFollowupVO.get(position));

        holder.bal.setText(null);
        holder.invam.setText(null);
        holder.customerName.setText(null);
        holder.promised.setText(null);
        holder.invpfu.setText(null);


        if (holder != null) {


            setValue(mpendingfollow.getCustomerName(),mpendingfollow.getCustomerId(), holder.linearLayout, holder.customerName);

            holder.invpfu.setText(mpendingfollow.getInvoiceNo());
            holder.promised.setText(mpendingfollow.getPromisedDate());
            holder.due.setText(mpendingfollow.getDueDate());
            holder.invam.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatAmount(mpendingfollow.getInvAmount()));
            holder.bal.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatAmount(mpendingfollow.getBalAmount()));



        }
    }
    void setValue(String cnam,long mpendingfollow,LinearLayout linearLayout,TextView cn) {

            if (customerId!=(mpendingfollow)) {
                showViews(linearLayout, cn,cnam);
                cn.setText(cnam);
                customerId=mpendingfollow;
            }
         else
            hideViews(linearLayout, cn);
    }
    private void showViews(LinearLayout layout, View seperator,String cnn) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void hideViews(LinearLayout row, View seperator) {
        row.setVisibility(View.GONE); // if there is a empty space change it with View.GONE
        seperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPendingFollowupVO.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public int position;


        protected TextView customerName, invpfu, due, promised, invam, bal;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {

            super(view);
            this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.head3);
            this.customerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customernamepfu);
            this.invpfu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.inv);
            this.due = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.due2);
            this.promised = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prom);
            this.invam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.over);
            this.bal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bal);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFragmentActionListener.setFragmentTitle("Communication");
            CommunicationFragment fragment = new CommunicationFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ooooo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

XML file of itemview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFDFDFDF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/head3"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="@{mPendingFollowupVO.customerName}"
            android:background="#2F75B5"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/customernamepfu"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head3"
        android:id="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Invoice#"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="#b1c1da"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="Due On"
            android:background="#b1c1da"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Promised"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="#b1c1da"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Inv amount"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="#b1c1da"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Balance "
            android:background="#b1c1da"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/head5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="@{mPendingFollowupVO.invoiceNo}"
            android:id="@+id/inv"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/due2"
            android:text="@{mPendingFollowupVO.dueDate}"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/prom"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="@{mPendingFollowupVO.promisedDate}"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="@{Double.toString(mPendingFollowupVO.invAmount)}"
            android:id="@+id/bal"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/over"
            android:text="@{Double.toString(mPendingFollowupVO.balAmount)}"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Model class is

```
public class PendingFollowupVO extends BaseObservable
{
    private  String CustomerName;
    private  long CustomerId;
    private  String InvoiceNo;
    private String DueDate;

    private  String PromisedDate;
    private  double InvAmount;
    private  double BalAmount;

    public PendingFollowupVO() {
        super();
    }

    public long getCustomerId() {
        return CustomerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(long customerId) {
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }

    public double getInvAmount() {
        return InvAmount;
    }

    public void setInvAmount(double invAmount) {
        InvAmount = invAmount;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return CustomerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        CustomerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return InvoiceNo;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        InvoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    public String getDueDate() {
        return DueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(String dueDate) {
        DueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getPromisedDate() {
        return PromisedDate;
    }

    public void setPromisedDate(String promisedDate) {
        PromisedDate = promisedDate;
    }

    public double getBalAmount() {
        return BalAmount;
    }

    public void setBalAmount(double balAmount) {
        BalAmount = balAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is with this condition `if(customerId!=mpendingfollow.getCustomerId())` you have written the logic considering it can scroll only down. If you can tell what exactly you are trying to achieve by storing previous customer id, it will become easier to solve your problem

Comment: this implies that.. if the customer id is already inserted then i want to make that linear layout invisible or hide.